# The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request

Tags: asp.net, vue.js

I have a server running asp.net core 3.1 and Vue. 
Everything works great but I have one specific page that when I do a http post I get the error
" The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request"

The strange thing is that my server is based off another project that is similar which doesn't have the problem.

I can't see why when I do this http post it is looking for index.html... I dont reference index.html anywhere!

I've looked at previous questions and my config looks fine e.g.

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});
```

the folder name is correct (I saw people had clientApp instead of ClientApp)

The folder is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot so I dont see any problems with that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add HttpPost to one of my APIs so when I did the HTTP post it didn't know where to post it to. 
I'm not sure why in my development build it worked though...kinda annoying

Comment: Similarly, if you rename a controller, but continue to POST to methods in that controller, this error can happen.